# Reading from a .txt file in java

Tags: java, java-io

I have a .txt file with some numbers. It looks like this:

```
1 4364 658 4328 666
2 5109 659 5100 638
3 4936 659 4904 677
4 4936 659 4957 639
5 5518 660 5602 672
```

I need to extract all numbers, except first column (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...), and use them for further calculation. Any help, tip would help a lot.

Comment: What specific help or tip would you like?  Open the file for reading, split each line by whitespace, reject the first item, use the remainder for calculation... ?

Comment: This can be divided into three easier problems: read a line into a String, split a String using space as separator, and convert a String of digits into a number.

Comment: Thats what I need. I need to separate them, and use them later to calculate something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate the first column like this.

```
import java.io.*;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("Path"))));
String line = null;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(line.substring(line.indexOf(" ") + 1));
}
br.close();
```

Now you manipulate the rest of the string as required.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the classes from the [java.io](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/package-frame.html) and [java.nio](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-frame.html) packages to. A [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) can read line by line your file:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new     File("Path"))));
String line = null;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    //do stuff in here
}
```

In Google [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html) there are helpful methods for [reading](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#readLines%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) a File.

The splitting of columns in this special case can be done by the [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method of the [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class.

```
line.split(" ");
```

For the splitting the usage of Google's [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) library might also be of big help for string splitting.

Handling of the numbers can be achieved by using the wrapper classes like [Long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html), [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) and so on, especially the static methods valueOf in the respective classes.

```
Long.valueOf("123");
```

Comment: Concur. Incidentally, Guava also makes reading the file much easier than the standard Reader approach.

Comment: Thanks for that hint. Actually Guava is full of such helpful stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Guava's Files.readLines() method to get the Strings into a List. From there, parsing out the rest can be done either with a Regex or by simply counting letters. The Integer class comes with a parseInt(String) method that will transform the individual Strings into Integers.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a double loop, one to split text in the file off the character '\n' which will give you a string array where each element is one line in the file, then iterate through that array and explode each row off the character ' '.  From that point on it is just a matter of ignoring the first element in the resulting array.

Here's the function I'm talking about:

[String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Thanks, I think I have figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

See the [RandomAccesFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) and the int Wrapperclass [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)

```
    RandomAccesFile f = new RandomAccessFile("file.txt", "r"); // r=read, w=write
    String line = f.readLine();
    String[] values = line.split(" ");
    int[] valueInt;
    for(int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
      valueInt[i-1] = Integer.pars(values[i]);
    }
```

or try the `RandomaccesFile.readInt()`-Methode

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ReadNumbers {

    public List<int[]> getNumbers(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        List<int[]> result = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String line = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] s = line.split("\\s+");
                int[] numbers = new int[s.length - 1];
                for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                    numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(s[i + 1]);
                }
                result.add(numbers);
            }
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ReadNumbers reader = new ReadNumbers();
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream("numbers.txt");
            List<int[]> numbers = reader.getNumbers(is);
            for (int[] n : numbers) {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int i : n) {
                    sum += i;
                }
                System.out.println("sum=" + sum);
            }
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException ignore) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FileReader to read the file:

```
File tFile = loadGradleResource("testdata.int");
FileReader fileReader = null;
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    String line = null;
    fileReader = new FileReader( tFile );
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( fileReader );
    while ( !( line = bufferedReader.readLine() ).isEmpty() ) {
        lines.add(line); 
    }
    bufferedReader.close(); 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

And then this method to tokenize each line:

```
for ( String lin : lines ) {
    String[] stritems = lin.split( " " );
    for ( String it : stritems ) {
       // this shows how to parse to integer
       System.out.print( Integer.parseInt( it ) + "," );
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```